# Excel restarts with a lag, idle Excel process running for 10 seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I am experiencing slowdown in in closing&opening Excel 2019. After I close one workbook, Excel keeps running for another few seconds, until it let's me open this or another book. No difference if it's a blank workbook or a big one.

[image]

Once a workbook is closed, an idle Excel process keeps running in the background. Only when it terminates, the new instance will fire up. Some kind of a weird wait state, when the new instance cannot start until the old one terminates.

Both Win10 and Office19 have latest updates. I tried uninstalling Office with the Uninstall tool - no effect.

Does anyone experience the same issue? Are there any known solutions?

Comment: Could you provide the detailed version information of Excel 2019 and Win10 to help me better do tests to reproduce the issue? As far as I know, Excel often opens multiple windows with single Excel instance. Do you use any Windows process optimize acceleration software? You can [perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) and check if you can reproduce the issue under Windows's clean boot mode.

Comment: @HerbGu, win10 Pro 18363.535, Excel 2019 10353.20037. No process optimization software used. I tested this on two machines, the only difference in config was SQL Server Express present on one and absent on the other one - the same result occurred. Performing clean boot has no effect. I don't recall when exactly the problem appeared. May be it arrived with the last Office update, which was mid December.

Comment: @HerbGu UPD: the lag appears _after_ opening a spreadsheet: If I try to open a file, then immediately close it, and open this or another file without delay, then Excel will freeze for a few seconds before actually opening the new file. The delay is approx 3-5 seconds. Bearable, but weird.